# Trying to launch HTML web gallery from a pen drive, don't know drive letter

Tags: hard-drive, drive-letter

I am trying to autorun a fairly simple HTML photo gallery from a pen drive to give to clients. Clearly I don't know what drive letter is going to be assigned to the drive in any particular pc.

How do I get a pen drive to autorun an index.htm file if I don't know the drive letter or will I need human intervention to get it to run?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](//superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged. In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts. For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/670225/david and http://superuser.com/users/670242/david. You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Adam gives a good answer. You don't need to know the drive letter, just make sure your references are "relative". But, at the same time, autorunning things is not a good thing and lots of computer block this behavior and treat it as threatening, in a malware-like way. Personally, I'd be very unhappy to receive a thumbdrive I was expected to allow to autorun, though your clients/customers/contacts may not be so worried. It's just something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

use autorun
1. Insert autorun.inf directly on pendrive.
2. write in autorun.inf:

```
[AutoRun]
shellexecute="index.html"
UseAutoPlay=1
```